# Do iOS apps need to be updated for the iPhone X's 120Hz touch array?

Tags: ios, iphone-x

The iPhone X has a [120Hz touch array](https://techcrunch.com/2017/10/31/review-the-iphone-x-goes-to-disneyland/). Do I need to update my app to support this faster touch array, especially if my app support drawing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:** No, you don’t need to update your app to support 120Hz touch delivery on iPhone X.

However, if you have an app that benefits from precise touch handling, like a drawing app, you can take advantage of 120Hz touch delivery to improve your user experience. And you may already have for iPad Pro — read on for details.

---

Apple’s [iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH108-SW11) talks about this a bit, if obliquely. The [Touch Input table](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH108-SW5) in that doc shows that iPhone X has a touch sample rate higher than its touch delivery rate, just like the first couple models of iPad Pro. (It’s also like how any iPad Pro gets Apple Pencil touches at 240Hz but delivers events only at 60Hz or 120Hz.)

Further down, it says:

> When the capture rate is higher than the delivery rate, multiple events are coalesced into one touch event whose location reflects the most recent touch. However, the additional touch information is available for apps that need more precision.

To get the extra touch information, ask the `UIEvent` object in your touch handler (`touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, or `touchesEnded`) for its [`coalescedTouches(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uievent/1613808-coalescedtouches), passing the `UITouch` you got in your touch handler.

Apple has a couple of articles that go into more detail on coalesced touches:

- [Getting High-Fidelity Input with Coalesced Touches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view/getting_high_fidelity_input_with_coalesced_touches)
- [Implementing Coalesced Touch Support in an App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view/getting_high_fidelity_input_with_coalesced_touches/implementing_coalesced_touch_support_in_an_app)

Also, if you’re doing anything with coalesced touches, you can probably also benefit from handling predicted touches. They also have a few articles about that, and some sample code that uses both:

- [Minimizing Latency with Predicted Touches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view/minimizing_latency_with_predicted_touches)
- [Incorporating Predicted Touches into an App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view/minimizing_latency_with_predicted_touches/incorporating_predicted_touches_into_an_app)

In short, if you’ve been optimizing your apps for faster (finger) touch handling and Apple Pencil on iPad Pro, you also benefit from faster touch handling on iPhone X.

If you don’t do anything, you’re just fine — only certain kinds of interaction are really improved by custom touch handling code, like drawing apps. And most likely Apple has optimized a bunch of the system touch handling code, like scroll views, gesture recognizers, the new swipe-to-Home and app switching gestures, etc, so your app would benefit from those for free.